# Count number of letters until one letters has changed

Tags: python

I want to count number of same letter at beginning between two words (letter by letter) until there's one different and return who has the most same letter.

This is my code :

```
def same(word, liste):
    letter = 0
    dico = dict()
    for i in liste:
        while word[letter] == i[letter]:
            letter += 1;
        dico[i] = letter;
        letter = 0;
    
    same = max(dico, key=dico.get)
    return same
```

But i get always this error of string index out of range, I've tried with much way but nothing

```
    while word[letter] == i[letter]:

IndexError: string index out of range
```

In input :

```
same('hello',['hi,'hell','helo'])
```

Output:

```
'hell'
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: I've just edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't go out of range in your while
verify the length of your word before `word[letter] == i[letter]`
 `while letter < len(word) and letter < len(i) and  word[letter] == i[letter]:`

gives you :

```
def same(word, liste):
    letter = 0
    dico = dict()
    for i in liste:
        while letter < len(word) and letter < len(i) and  word[letter] == i[letter]:
            letter += 1;
        dico[i] = letter;
        letter = 0;
    
    same = max(dico, key=dico.get)
    return same

print(same('blablabla',['blaze','bli']))

----------
>>> blaze
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a list comprehension along with basic substring logic:

```py
def same(word, liste):
    return max([x for x in liste if x in word], key=len)

print(same('hello',['hi','hell','helo']))  # hell
```

Comment: Really nice. But I don't completely follow - wouldn't `if x in word` in the comprehension always evaluate to `False` in this case?

Comment: Okay - my bad, it evaluates to `True` for "hell" - which means this solution won't work if we change the input to `same('hello',['hi','hellx','helo'])` - right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i've sometimes an error of max arg() is an empty sequence... How I can solve it ?

Comment: This could be happening in the event that none of the substrings are matching.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of zip, sum and max should give you the result -

```py
def same(word, liste):
  pairs = [zip(word, x) for x in liste]
  match_len = [sum([x == y for x, y in pair]) for pair in pairs]
  return lst[match_len.index(max(match_len))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet an other solution:

```
def same(word, liste):

def get_score(word, other):
    for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(word, other)):
        if l1 != l2:
            break
    return i

scores = {other:get_score(word, other) for other in liste}
return max(scores, key=scores.get)
```

In this case, I define the function `get_score` to count the number of common letters in a pair of words. I am sure to not run in IndexError because of the `zip` that makes an iterator over the 2 words.
Then I just did the same as you to get the word associated with the greatest score.